# Transform JSON with Groovy

Tags: json, groovy

I have a JSON file:

```
def jsonTxt =
'''
{
    "fields": [
       "key1",
       "key2",
       "key3"
    ],
    "table": [
      [
        1,
        2,
        "three"
      ],
      [
       4,
       5,
       "six"
      ],
      [
       7,
       8,
       "nine"
      ]
    ] 
}     
'''
```

Values in `fields` array are names (keys) for values in `table` array. I want to match them like this:

```
[
    {
        "key1": 1,
        "key2": 2,
        "key3": "three"
    },
    {
        "key1": 4,
        "key2": 5,
        "key3": "six"
    },
    {
        "key1": 7,
        "key2": 8,
        "key3": "nine"
    }
]
```

I tried with:

```
def result =  jsonSlurper.parseText(jsonTxt)

def myRes = result.table.collect {
     [
       key1 : it[0],
       key2 : it[1],
       key3 : it[2]
     ]  
}
```

And it returns what i expected. But how to avoid this hardcode? I mean, json property name I should take from `fields` and values for them like with increment indexes. If in the next JSON there will be another field, e.g. `accountId` instead of `key1` or as additional field, my code will be not working correctly.

Comment: Can't you boil it down to a JSON with say 10 lines? You may get an answer more quickly.  Additionaly I think your example does not match, the original JSON contains a table with `Campagn1-3` the result `POG1-2`

Comment: About example: it's my fault, tested with another values, but with the same structure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can collect over the rows of the table and "zip" the header with the
row and turn it into a map using `transpose` and `collectEntries`.

E.g.

```
result.table.collect{
  [result.fields, it].transpose().collectEntries() 
}
```